# ExecutorService causing out of memory exception after frequent shutdowns

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class ExecutorServiceTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new ExecutorServiceTest();
    }

    public ExecutorServiceTest() {
        while (true) {
            action();
        }
    }

    public String action() {
        String string = "";
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Callable() {
            @Override
            public String call() {
                return randomString();
            }
        });
        try {
            string = future.get(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException ex) {

        }
        future.cancel(true);
        executor.shutdownNow();
        return string;
    }

    public String randomString() {
        return "asdhkashdkjshakdasdsahdka";
    }

}
```

If you open up a task manager window and then run this class, you will notice that Java instantly uses a ton of memory. I have searched and debugged the class thoroughly but cannot find the memory leak.

What is causing `future.get(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);` to use up all the system memory and then crash?

Comment: Works fine on my end. Memory used gets up to around 80KB and then drops back to 10KB and begins rising again.

Comment: Maybe your garbage collector isn't running for some reason. You could try to call it manually.

Answer (score 7):

The `ThreadPoolExecutor` class has non-empty `finalize()` method (which performs the pool shutdown), so when garbage-collected it first goes to the finalizer queue (which is basically linked list) and processed by separate "Finalizer" thread. Even if the pool has no active tasks, shutting it down is quite slow. Depending on the hardware, OS and running conditions it's possible that new finalizers are added faster than processed by Finalizer thread, thus you may expect constant memory growth. In general you should not create and shutdown executors too fast.

Comment: I thought that as well so I added a `Thread.sleep` just before the `return String` but all that changes is the memory usage climbs up slower.

Comment: @ThreaT Try to add the delay before `shutdownNow()` not the `return` statement.

Comment: @TagirValeev: Is there an alternative option to `ExecutorService` for handling a large number of potential timeouts? For example, if you want to see if your ftp service is still running on any number of servers and you have a method to ping each server every 2 seconds? Instead of waiting for a response, you can just timeout and set the state to `false`

Answer (score 0):

I think the culprit is here:

```
while (true) {
    action();
}
```

This is spawning new threads aggressively (this is an expensive operation) and, IMHO, this leads to the memory issues and the crash.

Also, I think this is a bad example of using a single threaded executor. It is more suitable for serial execution of tasks in a single background thread. If you need to add a big number of new tasks, that have to be executed simultaneously, it's better to use a thread pool. Controlling the number of worker threads is going to prevent the program from running out of memory.

**Working code:**

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class ExecutorServiceTest {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new ExecutorServiceTest();
    }

    public ExecutorServiceTest() {
        while (true) {
            action();
        }
    }

    public String action() {
        String string = "";
        if (executor.isShutdown()) {
            Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Callable() {
                @Override
                public String call() {
                    return randomString();
                }
            });
            try {
                string = future.get(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
            future.cancel(true);
            executor.shutdownNow();
        }
        return string;
    }

    public String randomString() {
        return "asdhkashdkjshakdasdsahdka";
    }

}
```

Comment: _This is spawning new threads aggressively_ No, it doesn't. Their `action` method is blocking on the `Future#get`. There's plenty of time for the JVM to collect objects created and shutdown the executor service.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I think the thread will not be killed until `shutdownNow` is called. You are right about the blocking part, but still, under some conditions, spawning instances of ThreadExecutor can lead to this.

Comment: @DanailAlexiev: You are correct. I tried a different strategy based on your answer and now it works. I made `executor` global and added an `if` condition to check if it `isShutdown` and now it seems to work. Working code added to your answer.

Comment: Actually, my answer was not as detailed as @Tagir Valeev's. He has the better explanation here.

Comment: @DanailAlexiev: I made a mistake. The code never actually goes inside the `if (executor.isShutdown())` statement so it appears to be working but it's actually doing nothing.

Comment: @ThreaT Yeah, shutdown is never going to be called with this setup. If you remove the if completely, you will have sequential execution on the same executor and your memory should stay stable.